# Measuring voltage without a common ground

Tags: operational-amplifier, ground, differential

When measuring a power source voltage using a differential amplifier, without a common ground with amplifier supply, to which ground should we connect the differential amplifier resistor ground? V1 ground or V2 ground?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fUfcAc.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Both grounds should be tied together. Or you can try using the ground of each source and check the result.

Comment: @CFCBazarcom Both grounds can't be connected to each other, it should be isolated. I'm not doing experiments, I'm asking a question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your circuit is incomplete. There is no reference between your ground symbol and the power supply. You need this or the circuit will be floating relative to the supply rails and will drift. Connecting it to the mid-point of a pair of potential divider resistors from the PSU might be good enough.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fpawYT.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. Conventional schematic layout is signal running left to right and voltages arranged with positive to top and negative to bottom. Current generally flows top to bottom.*

R1, R2 and C1 form a ground reference relative to the power supply.

Comment: Thanks, is this how industrial PSUs with several isolated outputs measuring the voltages and display it on a single LCD?

Comment: If they're using the same LCD then the supplies are unlikely to be isolated.

Comment: Here's one product claiming channels are isolated and with a single display, [Link](https://www.rigolna.com/products/dc-power-loads/dp800/).

Comment: That's a laboratory PSU rather than an industrial one. They're probably using opto-isolated bi-directional digital communication between the control logic (including the display section) and each isolated power supply.

Comment: How an opto-coupler can so precisely output the voltage down to uV/mV region? is there an specific opto-coupler designed for this purpose?

Comment: " They're probably using opto-isolated bi-directional **digital** communication  ..." The commands and readings are converted to digital before transmission.

Comment: That's really fascinating, thanks again.

Comment: There are analog "isolation amplifiers" that work pretty much like an opamp with an output stage isolated from the rest via some coupling (optical, hall effect, etc) . They're pretty precise but expensive and slow. Most problems are solvable without cheating with an isolation amp.